# CSS3 Scale - Prevent from scalling text

Tags: html, css

So im facing an issue with some code, i have quickly written a simple example to show the effect in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0v0syunc/

What i need to do is prevent the TEXT from scaling but been struggling to do this, i used background-size before scale which worked fine but that's not supported in any version of IE including 10/11 - anyone have any ideas?

```css
h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.box {
  background: #000000;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h2>TEST TEXT</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you simply do it by adjusting the padding? http://jsfiddle.net/0v0syunc/2/

Comment: Thats just an example, its actually a scale effect with a background image so cannot do padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have asked the same question again. I'll rewrite the pre-existing strategy to your duplicate question:

---

The background and the text should be separated. The background can either be a pseudo-element (most semantically valid), or an empty element (e.g. `<div></div>`). The choice boils down to whether or not you want to support browsers that allow transitioning of pseudo elements (in the event that you want to use CSS transitions, but in your question you didn't mention it).

I'll use the pseudo-element method. The markup remains the same, but the CSS is slightly modified:

```css
h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.box {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.box::before {
    background-color: #000;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
.box:hover::before {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <h2>TEST TEXT</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing seems to be a little obtuse, however given that, you need to scale your child `h2` by the inverse ratio (1/1.3):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/0v0syunc/3/)

```css
.box:hover h2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.769);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.769);
  transform: scale(0.769);
}
```

The issue being that the scale is being applied to the parent and all children, so you need to reverse it for the child to 'nullify' the effect.

Comment: I have noticed 1 thing, on the .box locally i have the transition effect as well transition: all 2s ease-out 0s; which does not seem to work with changing the scale for the h2 - is this not possible? thanks for yout help